# Regarding different type of endpoint in wcf

Tags: wcf, wcf-endpoint

i am new in wcf and curious to explore in various part of wcf. i got this url **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358762%28v=vs.110%29.aspx**

from here i saw lots of different kind of endpoint exist but i was not aware of those and never used it

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:5555/Calculator" binding="netTcpBinding"
contract="CalculatorInterFace.ICalculator" name="NetTcpBinding_ICalculator" />
```

i understand about endpoint that it will have service address url and contract name & endpoint name just this much.

here are all different kind of endpoint

```
AnnouncementEndpoint
    A standard endpoint that is used by services to send announcement messages.

DiscoveryEndpoint
    A standard endpoint that is used by services to send discovery messages.

UdpDiscoveryEndpoint
    A standard endpoint that is pre-configured for discovery operations over a UDP multicast binding. 

UdpAnnouncementEndpoint
    A standard endpoint that is used by services to send announcement messages over a UDP binding. 

DynamicEndpoint
    A standard endpoint that uses WS-Discovery to find the endpoint address dynamically at runtime.

ServiceMetadataEndpoint
    A standard endpoint for metadata exchange.

WebHttpEndpoint
    A standard endpoint with a WebHttpBinding binding that automatically adds the WebHttpBehavior behavior

WebScriptEndpoint
    A standard endpoint with a WebHttpBinding binding that automatically adds the WebScriptEnablingBehavior behavior.

WebServiceEndpoint
    A standard endpoint with a WebHttpBinding binding.

WorkflowControlEndpoint
    A standard endpoint that enables you to call control operations on workflow instances.

WorkflowHostingEndpoint
    A standard endpoint that supports workflow creation and bookmark resumption.
```

so how do i know which endpoint i should use and when?also how do i know how the syntax will look like for different type of endpoint. please discuss as much as possible. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the endpoint that fits your requirements. You will nee to read a good book about WCF to find out the benefits and drawbacks of various endpoints.

For example, Interoperability may be a requirement. Then Basic-Http or Ws-Http probably fit. Maybe security is a requirement, then a Ws Fderation binding may be useful. Maybe your requirement is performance and you are guaranteed to be on the same machine, then it's probably a Named pipe binding.

There is no conclusive answer to this, other than "read a good book about it".